# SwiftUI: ICloud Documents alongside CloudKit

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, icloud-documents

I'm working on an app that uses both ICloud Documents and the new CloudKit. Both services are active on ICloud section under "Signing & Capabilities".

[image: Services and Containers for ICloud in XCode]

Because CloudKit is used in the whole app, I'll instantiate in the appDelegate like this

```swift
 lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "MyTestApp")

        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { _, error in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })

        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true

        return container
    }()
```

and made available via

```swift
struct MyTestApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

In a view within the app I'm trying to access the data from iCloud Documents so what I'm doing is:

```swift
struct TestReadICDView: View {
    private let iCloudDocumentsURL = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: "iCloud.it.mytestapp.oldcontainer")?.appendingPathComponent("MyTestApp.sqlite")

    init() {
        guard let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyTestApp", withExtension: "momd") else {
            fatalError("Error loading model from bundle")
        }

        guard let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL) else {
            fatalError("Error initializing mom from: \(modelURL)")
        }

        let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mom)

        let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)

        context.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy

        context.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc

        do {
            try psc.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: iCloudDocumentsURL, options: nil)
            let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Nota> = Nota.fetchRequest()
            let data = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            print("count: \(data.count)")
        } catch {
            fatalError("Error adding store: \(error)")
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World!")
    }
}
```

But every time I enter the view I got:

```
Thread 1: "executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity."
```

But the entity is specified in the NSFetchRequest.

I cannot understand why

Comment: "But the entity is specified in the NSFetchRequest"  At what line?

Comment: A Core Data novice says the following.  let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "My Core Data entity name")

Comment: @ElTomato let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Nota> = Nota.fetchRequest()
And no, your suggestion does not work :(